# Why does the PyChram IDE console not display a returned value unless print() is used?

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I am new to coding, Python, and JetBrains' IDEs. I recently installed PyCharm and Python 3.6.5.

I am trying to understand the difference in behavior between an interactive Python session and a Python program.

Is it normal that, when returning a value, the interactive session will print it, but a python program will not?

[image]

vs.

[image]

Comment: Why do you expect something would print if you don't call `print()`?

Comment: I've been using the terminal to learn and the returned values are displayed there. As i asked.. "Is this supposed to happen?" or not in PyCharm?

Comment: By "the terminal" do you mean an interactive Python session? In the interactive session, the `repr` of every expression is printed as it is evaluated (unless it evaluates to `None`, confusingly enough). That's only in the interactive session, not in a real program. So: no, running your program is not supposed to cause intermediate expressions to be printed to the console.

Comment: I do. Fantastic, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding as an answer from the comments:

At an interactive session with the Python prompt (normally `>>>`), each time an expression is evaluated the `repr()` of that expression is printed to the console.

For example:

```
>>> 1 + 2
3
>>>
```

However, that behavior is only in the interactive session. When you actually execute a Python script, nothing is printed to the console unless you use `print()` or some other I/O mechanism.

For example, if you run this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
1 + 2
```

Then nothing is printed.